# Using pure erlang OTP instead of elixir back-end with React.js and phoenix framework

Tags: reactjs, erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

I'm currently designing a web app and was planning on using a React.js front end, and was hoping to using Erlang OTP for the management of the server.
I've heard this is possible using the phoenix framework, but there's not a lot of information on using Erlang instead of the default Elixir,

Any tips welcomed :)

Comment: *but there's not a lot of information on using Erlang instead of the default Elixir,

Any tips welcomed* -- Erlang comes with an http sever called `inets`.  There are also third party servers called `Yaws`, `Cowboy`, `ChicagoBoss`, etc.  See here: https://elixirforum.com/t/yaws-vs-cowboy-and-phoenix/3348/3.  You might want to ask your question there.

Comment: *but there's not a lot of information on using Erlang instead of the default Elixir,*  That's because Phoenix is a framework that uses the Elixir programming language.  Your question is sort of like asking, I want to use Ruby on Rails, but there isn't a lot of information on using Python instead of the default Ruby.   That's not quite a fair comparison because in the Elixir programming language you can actually call erlang functions.  However, you still need to learn Elixir to use the Phoenix framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few tips and hints:

- To a large extent, elixir is *just* erlang with a different (some say more modern) syntax. And macros.
- Elixir and erlang both run their code on the same BEAM virtual machine.
- Elixir is built upon erlang and gives you the same cool features that erlang has.
- Elixir provides you with a lot of erlang based OTP libraries like Agent, GenServer, Supervisor, hot-code-reloading, etc.
- Elixir has some very nice built-in/first-class tools like `mix` and `ex_unit` that you will learn to appreciate.
- The Phoenix framework is written in elixir, so you *have* to use the elixir compiler to use Phoenix.
- All information and tutorials about Phoenix you will find on the web will be using elixir, not erlang.

Long story short: if you want to use the Phoenix framework, you have to use Elixir.